# Adding っぷり to a word: Does this have some easily defined meaning?

Tags: suffixes

I came across the following sentence in a Manga:

コケっぷりもかわいいです。

and I looked the sentence up in the translated Manga, where I found something like (translation was into German):

And she's also really funny. (Hach, und urkomisch ist sie auch noch)

I found コケ in a dictionary meaning "fool", so my first try would have been something like:

She's a bit foolish, but sweet.

But the っぷり is the missing element which I couldn't find anywhere. Does this modify the meaning of コケ in a specific way? Can it be used to modify other words as well? (According to google, it can, it seems to work even for nouns and verbs)

I also found this: http://www.lang.nagoya-u.ac.jp/nichigen/menu7_folder/symposium/pdf/8/01.pdf during my research, but couldn't make too much sense of it.

So, my question is: What does っぷり do? What kind of language/situation can it be used in (more informal, formal, ..)? How does it help me arrive at the translation suggested by the translator?

Comment: The コケ in the sentence and the コケ (or こけ or 虚仮) that means “fool” are different things.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The biggest mistake you have made is in trusting that translation, which is not even close to the original.

コケ does not mean "fool"; It is not even a noun.  It is from the verb こける, which means "to trip over", "to fall down", etc.

っぷり comes from ふ り, which means "the manner / way in which one performs an action".

食べっぷりがいい, for instance, means that someone eats a lot.
歌いっぷりがお父さんにそっくりね means "The way you sing really resembles your father's."

Thus, コケっぷりもかわいいです means "The way (someone) trips over is also cute."  This phrase is very informal but certainly not slanguish at all.  The コケ part is in katakana because こける is a fairly informal verb and it looks and feels lighter and more animated written in katakana.  The "regular" version is ころぶ.

Comment: I don't really trust that translation, I already found a lot of sentences that were downright wrong, but I try not to blame every discrepancy between what I think it means and the translation on the translator. 
The translation of "trip over" doesn't really fit the context, can it also maybe mean that someone is clumsy or that they have accidents? Or maybe just to fall? (It is said about a participant in a plane race who was previously shown running things over and losing control of her plane)... And back to っぷり: Is the phrase informal just because of the verb or also because of っぷり?

Comment: @fifaltra コケる also means "to fail", which is derived from the meanings "to trip over" or "to fall down" as said by Tokyo Nagoya.